# Convert Variant to String

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list on my primary worksheet containing the names of sheets in the workbook. I am trying to iterate over them but the Worksheets function expects a String and the values in the list return Variant types. I get a type mismatch error when I try to access the worksheet with a Variant expression. How do I convert a Variant to a String or is there another way to do this?

```
Dim allws As Range
Set allws = Worksheets("Summary").Range("A4:A21").Columns(1)
Dim str As String
str = allws.Item(1).Value 'Type mismatch
Set ws = Worksheets(str)
```

Comment: Side note: don't use `str` as a variable - there's the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for an array. More detail in the comments:

```
Dim allws As Range
Set allws = Worksheets("Summary").Range("A4:A21") ' no need for .Columns

Dim arr() as Variant
arr = allws.Value ' read the value into a 2D Variant array

Dim i as Long
For i = Lbound(arr, 1) to Ubound(arr, 1)
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(arr(i))
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems I can reference a worksheet by Variant after all. I was originally doing Set ws = Worksheets(allws.Item(1).Value) as a test and was getting a type conversion error, hence trying to convert it to a String. However when I remove the .Columns argument it works.